Reading spark-defaults.conf when using Spark REST HTTP server with a Java application
I'm using the Spark rest server to submit jobs. When submitting a pyspark application, the docs set the mainClass to be org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit, and then pass the python script as the appArgs. This means that the application is being run with SparkSubmit, which by default reads the spark-defaults.conf. For example:
curl -X POST http://localhost:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "s3n://<bucket-Name>/pi.py" ],
"appResource" : "s3n://<bucket-Name>/pi.py",
"environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
"spark.app.name" : "Simple App",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://localhost:6066"
}
}'

I'm trying to achieve the same behaviour with a Java spark job instead of Python. Most of the examples put the Job class itself as the mainClass, which means it's not being run with SparkSubmit, and the job does not have the configuration from spark-defaults.conf.
I could not find a way to use SparkSubmit with a jar file, since there is no option to supply the --class argument of SparkSubmit.
How do I specify the --class when submitting using the API, or alternatively make the class load the spark-defaults.conf in a different way?

Since there is no way to supply custom spark submit arguments, it can be achieved by not using the appResource, and instead prepending everything in the appArgs parameter, as follows:
curl -X POST http://localhost:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "--class", "com.class.YourClass", "path/to/jar.jar", "other arg1", "other arg2"],
"appResource" : "",
"environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
"spark.app.name" : "Simple App",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://localhost:6066"
}
}'```

